# Why these two code snippets yield the same result?

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

I was looking at a bunch of code which was like this and used `Comparator<T>` to sort an array of Strings ( The only reason I'm asking this question is that I'm curious about how `Comparator<T>` handles all this ):

```
 String[] names = //An string array

 Arrays.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return (o1.length()-o2.length());
        }
    });
```

I am familiar with this :

```
Arrays.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if(o1.length()>o2.length())
                return 1;
            else if(o1.length()==o2.length())
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    });
```

Which handles if the length the first String is bigger return 1 and return -1 if the second one is bigger and zero if they are of the same length. But the first snippet returns the difference between their length which could be less than -1 and more than 1. So how do `Comparator<T>` handle all this that they yield the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T):

> Returns: a **negative integer**, zero, or a **positive integer** as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

It doesn't need to be -1 or 1, but simply a negative integer or a positive integer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether this is what you mean, but the `Comparator` result is *qualitative*, not quantitative.

ANY result more than 0 means that the first argument is considered greater than the second one, and ANY result less than 0 means that the first argument is considered less (and 0, and 0 alone, means that they are considered equivalent).

The first implementation returns the distance, yes, but this is irrelevant information as far as `Comparable` is concerned. And by the way, the first implementation really shoud use [`Integer.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-).

Answer (score 1):

Check the Javadoc of `Comparator`'s [compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method :

> Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Only the sign of the returned integer matters, not its absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

The Comparator just looks at the sign of the result, so it can either be:

- `0`: the two elements are the same
- `positive`: o1 is bigger
- `negative`: o2 is bigger